# How to tell python 2 or 3 in Github?

Tags: github

I feel like this is a feature request/question for Github devs but since Github by default doesn't show you python 2 or 3 (but instead just python), how to easily tell other than cloning it or browsing in source code, assuming the Repo. document doesn't say (and often they just show pip without specifying whether it is pip2 or pip3.  I know I can just do pip search as well as I prefer if I can just see it right in the browser.

Maybe there is a chrome plugin but my googfu has no luck finding it thus far.

Comment: You could look at the package on https://pypi.python.org/pypi more metadata is listed there.

Comment: Sure but if I do that I may just as well do the other things I've mentioned; I guess I'm just annoyed at the fact that Github doesn't show this "natively".

Comment: Many libraries are cross-compat.  Github can't really know if code is Python 2 or Python 3 unless the author provides that metadata.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are asking for GitHub to tell you if a project or repository is Python 2.x or Python 3.x, and that is just not reasonably possible. If it is available through pip (pip2 or pip3) you can query that way (already mentioned), but it is worth explaining why GitHub cannot do what you ask :

- Python packages, projects, and/or code are not Python 2.x or Python 3.x (exclusive or), rather, it is possible two write code that works with either.
- GitHub could try to infer the prevailing version of Python within a repository, however, if they did so programmatically (even using sophisticated AI) it would be wrongs far too often.
- GitHub could try to force users to pick one, which would alienate many, frustrate many more, and generally provide no significant benefit to the community.
- Even if GitHub forced folks to choose, it is surprisingly common for authors to know know if their code will work fully in one version or the other.

Although you could envision GitHub trying to enforce designating repositories as "Python 2.x" or "Python 3.x", this makes little sense (see first bullet item) and would give the Python ethos community a severe allergic reaction since it's antithetical to the culture.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Github currently doesn't support distinguishing between Python 2 and 3 in the repository language statistics.**

Assuming you're referring to the Github language statistics on the front page of a repository (see screenshot of example repo below with red box around programming language statistics):

[image: Example of Github repo showing programming language percent distributions.]

This will not distinguish between Python 2 and Python 3 code. Apart from cross-compatability reasons, part of the reason why is that Python 2 and Python 3 code files sometimes share the same file extension names, and the [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) library which is used to calculate these statistics does not differentiate between them.

You can see [this section of the `languages.yml` file](https://github.com/danilaml/linguist/blob/00dc775daf12f34615647254f265a02c895481f1/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L3367-L3403) in the Linguist Github repo to see what's considered a Python file or not. Note that there's no distinction anywhere in the `languages.yml` between Python 2 and Python 3 code.